# Error in Stratified sampling

Tags: r, sampling

I used `SamplingStrata` package which includes `strata` function to select random samples. This selection is based on a field which has a unique ID and it is named as strata. Each of these IDs contains a minimum of 5 and maximum of 10 samples. You could see the below codes for selecting 3 samples from each strata and the error I receive. I am copying data elements below the R script. Please help out with the issue in error. Thank you.

```
#### R script and Data = samples
stratasamples<-strata(samples, stratanames = "TARGET_FID", size=3, method="srswor")


### Error 
Error in if (method != "srswr" & length(y) < size[i]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

### Data elements. ### Strata = TARGET_FID. Samples = JOIN_FID 
TARGET_FID  0   0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  2 2 
JOIN_FID    12 14 16 18 10 23 28 39 48 90 92
```

Comment: You should edit your question to include a library() call to load whatever package has the `strata` function and post some sample data that illustrates the problem. (Your verbal description of your data is unclear.)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem it's because you your dataframe contains NA.

Runs to check this

```
sum(is.na(samples$TARGET_FID))
```